# How to update Material UI select default style

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the select component and want to customize the first menuItem default background color, I'm not able to find the respective class, because if we click on inspect the background color is removed.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1.Click on select.

2.In the first menuItem, the default background is applied.

3.Right-click to inspect.

4.The background color is disappearing in the first menuItem, hence not able to inspect or update the background color.

**Expected:**

The background color of the first menuItem should be customizable.

Attached image for reference
[image]

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material/Select';

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setAge(event.target.value as string);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use `styled` components, you can just override the selectors. For example:

```
const StyledMenuItem = styled(MenuItem)<MenuItemProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: "green" // Hovered, non-selected item
  },
  "&:first-of-type": {
    backgroundColor: "aqua" // Wasn't clear -- is this what you're looking to do when you say "first"?
  },
  "&.Mui-selected": {
    backgroundColor: "red", // Selected, but not-hovered item
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "yellow" // Selected and hovered item
    },
  }
}));
```

*(The question was a bit unclear to me, so I just styled all basic options.)*

Which produces:

[image: No items selected but first item is styled]

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-swartz-9k6nnx?file=/demo.tsx

As for inspecting the element to see the applied classes, in Chrome:

1. Open the Select on mui.com's site.
2. Right-click on the element that you want to inspect and choose "Inspect".
3. In Chrome Dev Tools, right-click on the element and choose "Force State" > ":hover" (or whatever other state you want to force).

For example:
[image]